# Dynamically create list of jpanels swing/java

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, jscrollpane

I am attempting to create panel, PluginListPanel (extending JPanel), which will show a list of plugin panels which will respect the preferred height of the plugin's panel, but will force the width. I have a solution, but it is slow and has a weird bug. In the screenshot, there are two such panels, one to the left and one to the right:

[image]

I don't know different layout manager systems very well, but I know that the TOP field in the BorderLayout does what I want. So, I came up with this 'recursive' solution:

```
public PluginListPanel(List<PanelContainer> items) {        
    JPanel body = this;
    for (PanelContainer item : items) {
        body.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel panel = new PluginOnePanel(item);
        body.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel newBody = new JPanel();
        body.add(newBody, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        body = newBody;
    }
}
```

The problem I encounter is when I scroll, the system responds somewhat slowly, and the colour of the SamplePluginPanels is different (see picture below), even if the number of SamplePluginPanels is as low as 8.

The question is, how can I make this more elegant, not slow down the program and not miscolour the panels?

Any insights are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a vertical `Box` is the answer (actually 2, on both columns):

```
Box leftBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
Box rightBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

/* put them together */

setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
add(leftBox);
add(rightBox);
```

Also make sure, that the content of the scroll pane implements `Scrollable` and returns `true`, to `scrollableTracksViewportWidth()`. This will force equal widths.

Comment: This solution is nicer than mine :-) Unfortunately, it suffers the same issues with being slow and colours change as I scroll :-(

Comment: @tor That's possibly a flaw in `PanelContainer` or `PluginOnePanel`.

Comment: Both are dummy extensions of JPanel - the PluginOnePanel simply displays the panel contained in the PanelContainer within a frame, which as of right now is only a JPanel with a JLabel and the set background colour. There is nothing there except that...

Comment: I figured out something! The colour that I used as my background colour was SystemColour.textHighlight - if I use another colour, the issue goes away :D